# Ref null inside Popover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popover, react-ref

I am trying to autofocus an input element on opening of a popover. Here is the sandbox for it: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-bash-x6bj4?file=/src/App.js

Issue here is that the current property is always null on ref. Is this a case where forwardRef might help? I am not much aware of it so posting it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the contents of ```PopOver``` aren't mounted, meaning that the ```<input />``` doesn't exist yet when you execute the ```handleClick```

Comment: Like Adam said, you will have move your `.focus()` call to after the the button has been clicked, probably in a `useEffect` or something. The input element gets assigned to the ref after its clicked so you can't focus BEFORE the popover is open

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a ref for that, just add autoFocus to your input:

```
<input autoFocus placeholder="search" />
```

Comment: It works when I do it on your codesandbox. Make sure you type autoFocus correctly (F is uppercase)

Comment: It actually works. Sometimes we ignore the minor stuffs and overcomplicate things. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Since you control the `open` via state, which is async, when the `inputRef` tries to get the element, the state hasn't been updated, and the `Proper` children haven't been created.

You can add an async/await to the `setState` to make it works.

```
const handleClick = async event => {
  await setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  inputRef.current.focus();
};
```

[image: Edit heuristic-allen-hubry]

[image]

Comment: Nice way to approach it.+1

Comment: @AakashThakur I simply fix the fault inside the code, and if there are further implements like this, notice this kind of issue would help I guess

Answer (score 1):

You could simple add a callback after the setState, like this:

```
    this.setState(
      {
        anchorEl: e.currentTarget,
        isPopoverOpen: true,
      },
      () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (this.inputRef.current) {
            return this.inputRef.current.focus();
          }

          return null;
        }, 200);
      }
    );
  };
```

With the timeout you can secure that the popover is mounted and the input is visible, so the input will be focused when the timeout is passed. Using async/await is more for promises.