# createRef on element inside dynamic component is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using antd(https://ant.design/components/form/).  I have a `Form` inside a `Modal` and in constructor created a `ref` to the form.

When I open the modal I am trying to reset the fields by following this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ddtxj . When I click on the button that opens the modal, I call the onReset as shown in the example.

But I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resetFields' of null`.
When I `console.log(this.addCustomerFormRef);` I see `{current: null}`

I think the ref is null because the modal/form does not exist in the DOM yet ...or something like that. **It works when I do a `setTimeout` on my `onReset()` method.**

Can somebody tell me the right way to reset fields in the form?

constructor:

```
this.addCustomerFormRef = React.createRef();
```

Button to open modal:

```
 <Button type="primary" 
     onClick={() => { this.handleFormFieldsReset(); this.setState({ addModalVisible: true }) }}>
   Add Customer
 </Button>
```

Reset form method:

```
handleFormFieldsReset = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.addCustomerFormRef.current.resetFields(); //works with setTimeout
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61098998/11872246